# Regular expression for <a> tag replacement

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm new to regular expressions, but I'm trying to learn about it. I want to remove the  tag of a html text, and let only the inner text. Something like that:

```
Original: Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a> Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>
Result:  Lorem ipsum Google Lorem ipsum Bing
```

I'm using this code:

```
$patterns = array( "/(<a href=\"[a-z0-9.:_\-\/]{1,}\">)/i", "/<\/a>/i");
$replacements = array("", "");

$text = 'Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a> Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>';
$text = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$text);
```

It works, but I don't know if this code is the more efficient or the more readable.

Can I improve the code in some way?

Comment: For a start, it won't do anything on `<a title="" href='some bad link'>foo</a>`, except replacing the closing tag. So to sanitize input that no links remain this is a poor method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, PHP's [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) should do exactly what you need without regular expressions. If you want to strip only a specific tag (something `strip_tags()` can't do by default), there is a function in the [User Contributed Notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#96483).

In general, regexes are not suitable for parsing HTML. It's better to use a DOM parser like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) or one of [PHP's built-in parsers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Answer (score 5):

[Don't use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead.

Comment: that should read *Don't use regular expressions* **for parsing (x)HTML**. It's not like they are totally useless ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your content only contains anchor tags, then strip_tags is probably easier to use.

Your preg_replace won't replace if there are spurious spaces between a and href, or if there are any other attributes in the tag.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using regex is not a good idea. Having said that:

```
<?php
    $text = 'Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a> Lorem ipsum <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a>';
    $text = preg_replace(
        '@\\<a\\b[^\\>]*\\>(.*?)\\<\\/a\\b[^\\>]*\\>@',
        '\\1',
        $text
    );
    echo $text;
    // Lorem ipsum Google Lorem ipsum Bing
?>
```

This is a very trivial regex, its not bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

[You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Actually, you can't. (X)HTML is not a regular language, and as such can't be parsed by regular expressions.